# Different arguments in function

Tags: java, function, arguments

For example, I got a class X which got 2 fields named ex. aField and bField. In main class I got table of object class X and the function which should be called to times, but in first time it must change fields named aField and in second call must change fields named bField.

```
class X{
    int aField;
    int bField;
}
class Main{
    public X[] listX;
    public int amount;
    public static void requestedFunction(){
        for(int i=0; i<amount; i++){
            aField = 5;
            // bField = 5; 
            // or this one when called second time in code ;
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        amount = 10;
        listX= new X[amount];

        requestedFunction(); // thsi usage change fields named aFields
        requestedFunction(); // this usage change fields named bFields
    }
}
```

Is there any solution to make it in this way? Or I need to make 2 different functions?

Comment: You can overload a single method.

Comment: But it is still the same types of variables.

Comment: Your comment says *when called with a **second argument***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you can achieve this with

```
enum ExecutionType {
    ATYPE,
    BTYPE
}

public static void requestedFunction(ExecutionType eType){
    for(int i=0; i<amount; i++){
        if (eType==ExecutionType.ATYPE)
            aField = 5;
        else if (eType ==ExecutionType.BTYPE)
            bField = 5; 
    }
}

requestedFunction(ExecutionType.ATYPE);
requestedFunction(ExecutionType.BTYPE);
```

However, the correct way to achieve this is using two separate functions. This design is not so nice and has potential to cause serious headache for more complex scenarios.

You version that uses no parameters is also possible but defies more and more object oriented principals. It would be very difficult to understand the behavior of a function that does different things each time it's called.

Comment: I would go one step further and point out LOUDLY: although technically possible, it is really really bad style and will lead to problems in the future. Enums should **not** be used this way.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that using [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/). That library allows you to work classes/fields purely "string" based. Using the corresponding libraries, you could in essence write a method such as

```
public void putValue(X instanceOfX, int value, String fieldName)
```

and call that like

```
putValue(x, 5, "fieldA");
```

But: you better not do that! Reflection is complicated, and easy to get wrong! And it is not at all robust, when you decide to rename your fields later on, you will only notice at **run time** when your putValue() method is called with an outdated field name.

An alternative could be to use a Map, like:

```
Map<String, Integer> theValues = new HashMap<>();
```

so you can write code like:

```
theValues.put("A", 5);
theValues.put("B", 5);
```

But the real answer here: step back and look at the problem you actually want to solve. You see, it is already a bad idea to use allow writing class A into fields of class B. The whole idea of good OO design is to **not** disclose such implementation details. Fields are implementation details, and only that one owning class should know about those fields.

Good OO is about putting **behavior** into your classes. Meaning: your class X should not provide a field that other classes read from / write to. Instead that class should have methods that "do those things" for other methods (and please note: I am not talking about replacing field access with getter/setter methods here!).

Answer (score 0):

You could also pass a consumer and decide which field you want to modify.
Here is a small example :

```
public class Test {

private static Product[] products;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    doSomething((p) -> p.setName("CLOTHING")); //first loop
    doSomething((p) -> p.setId(1)); //second loop
}

public static void doSomething(Consumer<Product> productConsumer){
    products = getProducts();
    for(Product p : products){
        productConsumer.accept(p);
        System.out.println(p.toString());
    }

}

private static Product[] getProducts(){
    Product pr1 = new Product();
    pr1.setId(1);
    pr1.setName("Jacket");

    Product p2 = new Product();
    p2.setId(2);
    p2.setName("Shoe");

    return new Product[]{pr1, p2};
}

}

public class Product {

private int id;
private String name;
}
```